# Get values from HTML Input tag using vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Following is the HTML code:

```
<input name="tb_country" type="text" value="Germany" readonly="readonly" id="tb_country" class="detailtextbox">
```

Following is the VBA Code:

```
Private Sub Btn_Click()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
DIM country As IHTMLElement
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.visible = True
IE.navigate "https://intranetsite.com"
Do While IE.readyState<>READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Set doc=IE.document
Set Country = doc.getElementByID("tb_country")
Cells(3,2).value=Country.getAttribute("value")
IE.Quit
Set IE.Nothing
End Sub
```

But I am getting run time error 91

have tried many combinations like using class name and name, also have tried directly using country.value instead of getAttribute(), but still getting the same error.

Comment: *I am getting run time error 91* Which line?

Comment: runtime error 91 in line "Cells(3,2).value=Country.getAttribute("value")"

Comment: Did you try `Country.Value`?

Comment: Yeah, even that's not working